# как при помощи chardet поменять кодировку текста?

Tags: python

Есть текст в ascii, нужно при помощи команды chardet поменять его в кодировку UTF-8. не подскажете как? в документации не нашел

Comment: Похоже, что вы её вообще не читали. Chardet служит для определения кодировки и только. Изменить кодировку с помощью него невозможно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev чем тогда можно поменять?

Comment: [Встроенными средствами языка.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Любой текст в кодировке ASCII автоматически является текстом в кодировке UTF-8 и ничего менять не надо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказали выше chardet служит для определения кодировки. Кодирование и декодирование строк производится соответствующими методами .decode & .encode которые являются стандартными в python.
Например:

```
import chardet

s1 = 'абракадабра'
s2 = chardet.detect ( s1 ) [ 'encoding' ]
s3 = s1.decode( s2 ).encode( 'utf8' )
```